# Output not shown as XML table in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have made an application that creates an xsl and xml file, but the output is not shown as XML layout (like an expected HTML table).

What changes should be made in either the xml or xsl file to make the output look like a HTML table?

I checked various browsers but all show either the output below (Edge) or no output at all.

The xml file (newfile_output.xml) has content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"     
  href="C:\Users\Michel\Documents\newfile_output.xsl"?>
<patch_list xml:lang="en">
  <patch>
    <type>Program</type>
    <id>I-B000</id>
    <name>Jazz Dry/Amb1 Kit SL1,2</name>
    <favorite> </favorite>
    <category>Drums</category>
    <subcategory>Natural Drums</subcategory>
    <setlistname></setlistname>
    <setlistslotreferenceid></setlistslotreferenceid>
    <setlistslotreferencename></setlistslotreferencename>
    <description></description>
  </patch>
   .... 
  <patch>
    <type>WaveSequence</type>
    <id>U-F012</id>
    <name>Looped Cello G Vibrato</name>
    <favorite> </favorite>
    <category></category>
    <subcategory></subcategory>
    <setlistname></setlistname>
    <setlistslotreferenceid></setlistslotreferenceid>
    <setlistslotreferencename></setlistslotreferencename>
    <description></description>
  </patch>
</patch_list>
```

The xsl file (newfile_output.xsl) has the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="/">
   <html>
   <body>
     <h2>Patch List</h2>
     <table border="1">
       <tr bgcolor="#80a0ff">
         <th>ListSubType</th>
         <th>Id</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Fav</th>
         <th>Category</th>
         <th>Sub Category</th>
         <th>Set List Slot Reference Id</th>
         <th>Set List Slot Reference Name</th>
         <th>Set List Name</th>
         <th>Description</th>
       </tr>
       <xsl:for-each select="patch_list/patch">
         <tr>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="type"/></td>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="id"/></td>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="favorite"/></td>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="category"/></td>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="subcategory"/></td>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="setlistslotreferenceid"/></td>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="setlistslotreferencename"/></td>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="setlistname"/></td>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="description"/></td>
         </tr>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </table>
   </body>
   </html>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output looks like:

```
Program I-A000 KRONOS German Grand Keyboard A.Piano Program I-A001 German 
Dark Grand Keyboard A.Piano Program I-A002 R.Ferrante German Grand Keyboard 
A.Piano Program I-A003 German New Age Grand Keyboard A.Piano Program I-A004 
L.Mays German Grand Keyboard A.Piano Program I-A005 German Grand + VPM 
Keyboard A.Piano Program I-A006 KRONOS Japanese Grand Keyboard A.Piano 
Program I-A007 Japanese ...
```

Comment: `href="C:\Users\Michel\Documents\newfile_output.xsl"` is not a proper URL. Make a proper URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried with my IE browser it's working fine.
Check File permission and directory path of the referenced XSL file

Comment: I accepted this answer, since I found out the real problem was an illegal HTML character inside the part I did not show. I thought it would be part of the header/footer or XSL file.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
```

after your

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

element. It should look like

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
  ...
```